# Using the edit tag, is it possible to show previously attached files?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have a multi-part form that is set up with freeform. After submission, I display a confirmation page where the user can view the data they entered, and if they want to make changes there is a link to the 'edit' page that uses the {exp:freeform:edit} tag.

On the edit page, all of the freeform data populates correctly except for the file fields. I have a group of file fields on the 3rd page of the form and they show up as "no file selected" even though there were files uploaded when the form was originally submitted. Is there a way to leave the attached files in place on the edit page so that the user won't have to upload them again when making edits?

Thank you for your help!